# Show: $\langle n \vert \psi \rangle \langle \psi \vert n \rangle = \langle -\psi \vert n \rangle \langle n \vert \psi \rangle$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, partition-function, grassmann-numbers, coherent-states

The book (Altland and Simons, Condensed Matter Field Theory, Ch. 4.2) I am reading makes use of the identity
\begin{equation}
\langle n \vert \psi \rangle \langle \psi \vert n \rangle = \langle -\psi \vert n \rangle \langle n \vert \psi \rangle,
\end{equation}
when deriving the field integral for the quantum partition function. The conventions are
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  \vert n \rangle &= c^+_{i_n}...c^+_{i_1}\vert 0 \rangle \\
  \vert \psi \rangle &= \exp(-\sum_j\psi_jc^+_j)\vert 0\rangle \\
  \{\psi_j,c^+_k\} &= 0 =\{\psi_j,c_k\} \\
  \langle \psi \vert &= \langle 0 \vert \exp(\sum_j \bar{\psi}_jc_j).
\end{split}  
\end{equation}
My attempt to show this was to use the properties of coherent states
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
   \langle n \vert \psi \rangle &= \psi_{i_1}...\psi_{i_n} \\
   \langle \psi \vert n \rangle &= \bar{\psi}_{i_n}...\bar{\psi}_{i_1} \\
   \langle -\psi \vert n \rangle &= \langle 0\vert \exp(\sum_j(-\bar{\psi}_j)c_j)c^+_{i_n}...c^+_{i_1}\vert 0 \rangle \\&= (-)^n \langle \psi \vert n \rangle
\end{split}  
\end{equation}
And then
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  \langle n \vert \psi \rangle \langle \psi \vert n \rangle &= \psi_{i_1}...\psi_{i_n}\bar{\psi}_{i_n}...\bar{\psi}_{i_1}=((-)^n)^n \langle \psi \vert n \rangle \langle n \vert \psi \rangle \\
  &= ((-)^n)^{n-1} \langle -\psi \vert n \rangle \langle n \vert \psi \rangle = \langle (-)^n \psi \vert n \rangle \langle n \vert \psi \rangle.
\end{split}  
\end{equation} 
There must be a mistake somewhere, but I just can't figure out where.

Comment: Please put the equation your trying to show in the main body of your question (as well as the title)

Comment: Isn't the equation simply equivalent to $\langle \psi | n \rangle = \langle - \psi | n \rangle$? Which I don't see how it could be true in the general case, because if this is true for all $|n\rangle$ then $|\psi\rangle = |-\psi \rangle$.

Comment: I understand that usage of MathJax is highly discouraged for titles.

Comment: @Javier, no, because you can't cancel grassman numbers like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a mistake in your consideration. Let's stop before the last step in your equalities and look at
$$
\langle n|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|n\rangle = ((-)^n)^{n-1} \langle-\psi|n\rangle\langle n|\psi\rangle.
$$
We actually have
$$
((-)^n)^{n-1} = (-)^{n(n-1)} = 1
$$
because of the number $n(n-1)$ is even for every integer $n$.